# laravel, recall resource route inside closure on routes.php

Tags: laravel-5, controller, routes

I already implement this code and it works,
function to return/generate html from view file, i add the view() method to the controller

```
//i'm ok with this and did works
Route::get('/page/{name}', function($name){
    if(class_exists("App\Http\Controllers\\".$name."Ctrl")){
        return App::make("App\Http\Controllers\\".$name."Ctrl")->view();
    }
    else{
        return "Page tidak ditemukan";
    }
});
```

Now i want to implement this on **resource route**, but cannot find technic/method to function the same way as above

```
Route::resource('/data/{name}', function($name){

    //check first if controller exists
    if(class_exists("App\Http\Controllers\\".$name."Ctrl")){
        //need some Kind Of method or hack i presume
        // so the request is processed as defined by the standar resource route
        //
        //NEED HELP ON THIS FUNCTIONALITY
        //
    }
    else{
        return "Page tidak ditemukan";
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not a good way to make routes, choosing what file to run based on unfiltered user input is asking for the worst kind of trouble and defeats the purpose of using routing. You should make a call to `Route::resource` for every resource controller you have.

Comment: yes, i realize thats true, i had another whitelisting filename filter that i used, or maybe i use your suggestion that was the worst kind afterall and use the suggested best practices